# Google Play store will allow the app with Targeted SDK 15 for production release ? where already beta app submitted with Targeted SDK 23

Tags: android

i need help for submitting my app to google play store, 
Recently i have submitted my app with Targeted SDK version 23 for beta testing but now i want to submit the app with targeted SDK version 15 for production, will the play store allow me to submit the app or will it through any exception.

-i have tried by submitting the new app to beta testing with targeted SDK version 15 but it showed me an error saying that "Permission model downgrade PROBLEM: Users that have the APK version code XXXX1, which  targets SDK 23 or higher, will receive an error when they attempt to upgrade to this apk XXXX2 because it targets SDK 15."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that since android N (api v23) with have a new permision model instead of asking the user for permissions on installation on the play store, it ask for each permission on runtime when you decide, so if a user needed to give permission to something for your app to work and you haven't asked for it programatically when you update what would happen is that there would be not way for this user to allow this permission and your app will crash.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perm

Google won't allow you to downgrade your sdk api in any channel, not on release, not on beta given that.

> Keep in mind that once you publish an APK targeting API level 23 or higher, you won't be able to submit an update targeting API level 22 or lower on any channel. 2016 Jun 15
>
> It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below).

[image]

Comment: The thing is My existing production app is running on Targeted SDK version 14, will it allow the new app with android SDK level 15?? where i have an app in beta release with android target SDK level 23 which is used only for beta testing and not yet published to all the users.

Comment: Until you deploy your beta version with SDK > 23, it won't be really updating devices with level 23 so you should be able to do that, but after you publish your beta version to production, you won't.

Comment: Happy to hear it, thank you. i will not publish my beta version to production i will upload new apk to production directly.

Comment: we have tried to submit the app with SDK15 to production but unfortunately google play console is limiting to upload the apk as the beta app was submitted with SDK23. kindly suggest any option so that we can submit our app with SDK15 to production.